# Unable to click button in iframe using Webdriver which has property <em unselectable="on">

Tags: javascript, iframe, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on 'Show in full screen mode' button present in our application.

Following is the html content found using firebug

```
    <iframe class="gwt-Frame" src="/designer/editor/?uuid=1cca23be-5a43-4506-962e-b9124d463469&profile=jbpm" domain="bg-sipstage1" style="width: 100%; height: 580px;" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html class=" ext-strict x-viewport x-viewport" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:b3mn="http://b3mn.org/2007/b3mn" xmlns:ext="http://b3mn.org/2007/ext" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:atom="http://b3mn.org/2007/atom+xhtml">
    <head profile="http://purl.org/NET/erdf/profile">
    <body id="jbpmdesigner" class=" ext-gecko x-border-layout-ct x-body-masked" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <div id="ext-comp-1008" class=" x-panel x-panel-editor-north x-border-panel x-panel-noborder" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1625px;">
    <div id="ext-gen18" class="x-panel-bwrap">
    <div id="ext-gen19" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder" style="height: 24px; width: 1625px;">
    <div id="ext-comp-1014" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder">
    <div id="ext-comp-1023" class="x-toolbar x-small-editor" style="height: 19px;">
    <table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td id="ext-gen299">
    <td id="ext-gen307">
    <td id="ext-gen315">
    <td id="ext-gen323">
    <td>
    <td id="ext-gen332">
    <td id="ext-gen340">
    <td id="ext-gen348">
    <td id="ext-gen356">
    <td id="ext-gen1095">
    <td id="ext-gen365">
    <td id="ext-gen373">
    <td id="ext-gen1092">
    <td id="ext-gen382">
    <td id="ext-gen390">
    <td id="ext-gen484">
    <table id="ext-comp-1046" class="x-btn-menu-wrap x-btn x-btn-icon " cellspacing="0" style="width: 36px;"></td>
    <td id="ext-gen493"><table id="ext-comp-1048" class="x-btn-menu-wrap x-btn x-btn-icon " cellspacing="0" style="width: 36px;"></td>
    <td id="ext-gen502"><table id="ext-comp-1050" class="x-btn-menu-wrap x-btn x-btn-icon " cellspacing="0" style="width: 36px;"></td>
    <td id="ext-gen510"><table id="ext-comp-1053" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn x-btn-icon " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: auto;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="x-btn-left" id="ext-gen736">
    <td class="x-btn-center" id="ext-gen755">
    <em unselectable="on"><button id="ext-gen512" class="x-btn-text" type="button" style="background-image: url("/designer/images/fullscreen.png");" title="Show in full screen mode"> </button>
    </em>
    </td>
    <td id="ext-gen735" class="x-btn-right">
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
```

I am able to identify or find the 'Show in full screen mode' using following xpath's

1) public By FullScreen=By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-comp-1053']/*/*/*[2]/*/*");

or

2) public By FullScreen=By.xpath("//*[contains(@title, 'Show in full screen mode')]");

However unable to click the button. I used following two methods
I tried using .click() method

```
Actions.WaitForElement(......FullScreen);
Actions.MoveToElement(.......FullScreen);
driver.findElement(........FullScreen).click();
```

Even i tried using javascript to click

```
WebElement fullscreen=driver.findElement(WorkflowLocators.FullScreen);
JavascriptExecutor executor2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
executor2.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", fullscreen);
```

In both the scenario its failing to click the button.

Comment: Please, post what exceptions you get or what exactly happens. Because  it's quite hard to help when you don't know the exact problem. In the first place, do you switch to frame?

Comment: @Alexander- Yes i used switchTo() for the frame. I am not getting any exception. Only issue is click operation is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Having nested quotation marks in your html tags (like `style="background-image: url("/designer/images/fullscreen.png");"`) might make it difficult for xpath to parse it.  Consider replacing the inner quotations with single quotes.

As for your specific question, you should be able to use a simpler method of locating the element you want to click using just the id of the button element.  ID attributes on web elements should be unique in that page.  Try using `By.id("ext-gen512")`.